# Rails & Mogli - get users friends' ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Rails 3 & mogli to connect to facebook. This code get's me a user object.

```
client = Mogli::Client.new(session[:at])
user = Mogli::User.find("me", client)
```

I've seen from the documentation that mogli has classes for all the object types. (EG: albums, events, etc) But i don't know how to retrieve connections. (EG: friends)

Basically i need to get a list of the user's friends with their id's. Because `user.friends` is only an array of their names.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

err. i feel stupid. `@user.friends` is an array of `Mogli::User` objects. `@user.friends.inpect` was calling `to_str` on them automatically.

Comment: And how to retrieve uid (of logged user)?

Comment: I'm not able to test this right now, but it's probably `Mogli::User.find("me", client).id`